# How should I put two ids in an onEvent?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game and i’m trying to make an onEvent block for two ids since i want two of my buttons to be able to have the same event when clicked. However, I am having trouble putting the two ids together in the same onevent id with it functioning properly. I have tried using “and” and “or” statements but they don’t work for both ids.As well as tried to use an array but I wasn’t really sure how to.I am new at coding and not very good hope someone can help!

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow! show us the code you have tried.  A snippet is the best way to get a quick answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(){

console.log(event.target);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='myFunction()'>one</button>
<button onclick='myFunction()'>two</button>
```

Comment: i’m confused is your recommendation to just make another onEvent button? because that is exactly what i don’t want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the same class for the two buttons instead of binding to separate IDs - then you can just bind to that class.

Classes in HTML are described here:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

You use classes instead of, or in addition to, 'id' attributes, when you want to affect many elements in the same way.

In this case, you can use JavaScript to bind a function to all elements which share a class, rather than binding over and over again to elements with different ids.

Comment: Do you know any other ways with out using a class because i don’t know how to make one or even what that is 

Comment: i tried using a variable to place for the id but that was no use as well